# Using JavaScript closures in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, mootools, closures, settimeout

I'm using setTimeout to emulate rendering, and I came to the structure like this:

```
var Renderer = new Class (
{
    Implements: Events,

    initialize()
    {
        this.onRender();
    },

    onRender: function()
    {
        // some rendering actions
        setTimeout(this.onRender.bind(this), 20);
    }
});
```

Does that code have potential memory leaks because of infinite nesting of closures? Or everything is ok? The only solution I came so far is to rewrite it to usual

```
function Renderer()
{
    var onRender = function()
    {
        // rendering
        setTimeout(onRender, 20);
    };
    onRender();
};
```

But I don't want to lose Mootools Events and Classes.
For some reasons I can't use a "singleton" (like window.renderer = new Renderer();) too

Comment: Where is the infinite nesting? Your question/concern is not clear.

Comment: it's all good. btw, you can just do `this.onRender.delay(20, this);` in mootools. and your code is wrong, it lacks initialize: function() but i guess you threw that in as an example.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code is fine, but Andy's answer is misleading because it confuses the [*scope chain*](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/#scope-chain) with [*execution context*](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-1-execution-contexts/) and, by extension, *call stack*.

First, `setTimeout` functions **do not** execute in the global scope.  They still [execute in a closure](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/ShcBQ/) and can access variables from outer scopes.  This is because JavaScript uses **static scope**; that is, the *scope chain* of a function is defined at the *moment that function is created* and never changes; the scope chain is a property of the function.

*Execution context* is different and separate from the *scope chain* in that it is constructed at the time a function is invoked (whether directly – `func();` – or as the result of a browser invocation, such as a timeout expiring).  The execution context is composed of the activation object (the function's parameters and local variables), a reference to the scope chain, and the value of `this`.

The *call stack* can be thought of as an array of execution contexts.  At the bottom of the stack is the global execution context.  Each time a function is called, its parameters and `this` value are stored in a new 'object' on the stack.

If we were to change your `onRender` function to simply call itself (`this.onRender()`), the stack would quickly overflow.  This is because control would never leave each successive `onRender` function, allowing its execution context to be popped off the call stack.  Instead, we go deeper and deeper with each `onRender` waiting for the next `onRender` to return, in an infinite cycle broken only when the stack overflows.

However, with a call to `setTimeout`, control returns immediately and thus is able to leave the `onRender` function, causing its execution context to be popped off the stack and discarded (to be freed from memory by the GC).

When the timeout expires, the browser initiates a call to `onRender` from the global execution context; the call stack is only two deep.  There is a new execution context – which by default would inherit the global scope as its `this` value; that's why you have to `bind` to your `Renderer` object – but it still includes the original scope chain that was created when you first defined `onRender`.

As you can see, you're not creating infinite closures by recursion because closures (*scope chains*) are created at function definition, not at function invocation.  Furthermore, you're not creating infinite execution contexts because they are discarded after `onRender` returns.

We can make sure you're not leaking memory by [testing it](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/jL7Ty/).  I let it run 500,000 times and didn't observe any leaking memory.  Note that the maximum call stack size is around 1,000 *(varies by browser)*, so it's definitely not recursing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, josh. That's exactly what I wanted to clarify. I was concerned that by using a closure when passing a callback for setTimeout I'll somehow deny the context of onRender to pop off the stack. I ran tests and couldn't notice any memory overflow. But I was aware of using closures freely because I'm not used to it.