# Add key value pair to all objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to add a key:value parameter to all the objects in an array.

eg:

```
var arrOfObj = [{name: 'eve'},{name:'john'},{name:'jane'}];
```

Now I wanted to add a new parameter, isActive to all the objects so the resulting array will look like.

eg:

```
    [{
    name: 'eve',
    isActive: true
}, {
    name: 'john',
    isActive: true
}, {
    name: 'jane',
    isActive: true
}]
```

I can always loop through the array and insert a key,value pair. But was wondering if there was a better way to do so

Comment: `arrOfObj.map(o => o.isActive = true;)`

Comment: better would be arrOfObj.map(o => (o.isActive = true)); This would not throw no-return-assign error on ESLint and considered a best practice as well.

Comment: @redu it will not add to but replace the array with only `[true,true,..]`.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is a best choice for this case

---

**tl;dr - Do this:**

```
const newArr = [
  {name: 'eve'},
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'jane'}
].map(v => ({...v, isActive: true}))
```

The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function **won't modify** the initial array, but creates a new one.
This is also a good practice to keep initial array unmodified.

---

**Alternatives**:

```
const initialArr = [
      {name: 'eve'},
      {name: 'john'},
      {name: 'jane'}
    ]

const newArr1 = initialArr.map(v => ({...v, isActive: true}))
const newArr2 = initialArr.map(v => Object.assign(v, {isActive: true}))

// Results of newArr1 and newArr2 are the same
```

**Add a key value pair *conditionally***

```
const arr = [{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 2}]   
const newArr1 = arr.map(v => ({...v, isActive: v.value > 1}))
```

What if I don't want to add new field at all if the condition is false?

```
const arr = [{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 2}]   
const newArr = arr.map(v => {
  return v.value > 1 ? {...v, isActive: true} : v 
})
```

**Adding *WITH* modification of the initial array**

```
const initialArr = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
initialArr.forEach(v => {v.isActive = true;});
```

This is probably not a best idea, but in a real life sometimes it's the only way.

---

**Questions**

- **Should I use a spread operator(`...`), or `Object.assign` and what's the difference?**

Personally I prefer to use spread operator, because I think it uses  much wider in modern web community (especially react's developers love it). But you can check the difference yourself: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926019/930170)(a bit opinionated and old, but still)

- **Can I use `function` keyword instead of `=>`?**

Sure you can. The fat arrow (`=>`) functions play a bit different with `this`, but it's not so important for this particular case. But fat arrows function shorter and sometimes plays better as a callbacks. Therefore the usage of fat arrow functions is more modern approach.

- **What Actually happens inside map function: `.map(v => ({...v, isActive: true})`?**

Map function iterates by array's elements and apply callback function for each of them. That callback function should return something that will become an element of a new array.
We tell to the `.map()` function following: take current value(`v` which is an object), take all key-value pairs away from `v` andput it inside a new object(`{...v}`), but also add property `isActive` and set it to true (`{...v, isActive: true}`) and then return the result. Btw, if original object contains `isActive` filed it will be overwritten. `Object.assign` works in a similar way.

- **Can I add more then one field at a time**

Yes.

```
[{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 2}].map(v => ({...v, isActive: true, howAreYou: 'good'}))
```

- **What I should not do inside `.map()` method**

You shouldn't do any side effects[[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129105/javascript-closures-and-side-effects-in-plain-english-separately), [link 2]](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0), but apparently you can.

Also be noticed that `map()` iterates over each element of the  array and apply function for each of them. So if you do some heavy stuff inside, you might be slow. This (a bit hacky) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39828104/930170) might be more productive in some cases (but I don't think you should apply it more then once in a lifetime).

- **Can I extract map's callback to a separate function?**

Sure you can.

```
const arr = [{value: 1}, {value: 1}, {value: 2}]   
const newArr = arr.map(addIsActive)

function addIsActive(v) {
    return {...v, isActive: true}
}
```

- **What's wrong with old good for loop?**

Nothing is wrong with `for`, you can still use it, it's just an old-school approach which is more verbose, less safe and mutate the initial array. But you can try:

```
const arr = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 arr[i].isActive = true
}
```

- **What also i should learn**

It would be smart to learn well following methods [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). These methods can solve 80% of what you usually want to do with arrays.

Comment: return not necessary inside map function

Comment: "const initialArr = [
      {name: 'eve'},
      {name: 'john'},
      {name: 'jane'}
    ]

const newArr1 = initialArr.map(v => ({...v, isActive: true}))
const newArr2 = initialArr.map(v => Object.assign({}, {isActive: true}))

// Results of newArr1 and newArr2 are the same "


This part is not right. newArr1 and newArr2 are not same. Please correct answer

Answer (score 123):

You can do this with `map()`

```js
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve'
}, {
  name: 'john'
}, {
  name: 'jane'
}];

var result = arrOfObj.map(function(o) {
  o.isActive = true;
  return o;
})

console.log(result)
```

If you want to keep original array you can clone objects with `Object.assign()`

```js
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve'
}, {
  name: 'john'
}, {
  name: 'jane'
}];

var result = arrOfObj.map(function(el) {
  var o = Object.assign({}, el);
  o.isActive = true;
  return o;
})

console.log(arrOfObj);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: return is unnecessary

Comment: @splay...In this case it is, since the result of map is being assigned to the result variable. It's more obvious also that map returns a new array (instead of using it as a throw away for each)

Comment: isn't map looping through the array in background?

Answer (score 21):

I would be a little cautious with some of the answers presented in here, the following examples outputs differently according with the approach:

```
const list = [ { a : 'a', b : 'b' } , { a : 'a2' , b : 'b2' }]

console.log(list.map(item => item.c = 'c'))
// [ 'c', 'c' ]

console.log(list.map(item => {item.c = 'c'; return item;}))
// [ { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }, { a: 'a2', b: 'b2', c: 'c' } ]

console.log(list.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { c : 'c'})))
// [ { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }, { a: 'a2', b: 'b2', c: 'c' } ]
```

I have used *node v8.10.0* to test the above pieces of code.

Comment: These days, with all the new features node v8+ brings, using Object.assign is a very good and elegant option.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var arrOfObj = [{name: 'eve'},{name:'john'},{name:'jane'}];
const result = arrOfObj.map((name) => {
    name["isActive"] = true;
    return name;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this:

```
arrOfObj.forEach(function(item){item.isActive = true;});

console.log(arrOfObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Redu's solution is a good solution

> arrOfObj.map(o => o.isActive = true;)
>   but Array.map still counts as looping through all items.

if you absolutely don't want to have any looping here's a dirty hack :

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "isActive",{
  value: true,
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true
});
```

my advice is not to use it carefully though,
it will patch absolutely all javascript Objects (Date, Array, Number, String or any other that inherit Object ) which is really bad practice...

Comment: **o.isActive = true** should either be `o.isActive == true` or just `o.isActive`

Answer (score 1):

```
_.forEach(arrOfObj,(arrVal,arrIn) => {
             arrVal.isAcitve = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arrOfObj = [{name: 'eve'},{name:'john'},{name:'jane'}];
let newArr = arrOfObj.map(i => ({...i,isActive: true}));
```

Here what i did was i spread the current object and insert a new key with a value to the object and return it as a new object.

Comment: When posting an answer it is good to check existing answers and make your answer is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the array and inserting a key, value pair is about your best solution. You could use the 'map' function but it is just a matter of preference.

```
var arrOfObj = [{name: 'eve'},{name:'john'},{name:'jane'}];
arrOfObj.map(function (obj) { 
   obj.isActive = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
var arrOfObj = arrOfObj.map(function(element){
   element.active = true;
   return element;
}
```

Map is pretty decent on compatibility: you can be reasonably safe from IE <= 9.

However, if you are 100% sure your users will use ES6 Compatible browser, you can shorten that function with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), as @Sergey Panfilov has suggested.

Comment: Return is not necessary

Comment: @splay It is if you want to use `.map()` properly. You should be using `.forEach()` if you only want to use it as a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arrOfObj = [{name: 'eve'},{name:'john'},{name:'jane'}];
    var injectObj = {isActive:true, timestamp:new Date()};

    // function to inject key values in all object of json array

    function injectKeyValueInArray (array, keyValues){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!array.length)
                return resolve(array);

            array.forEach((object) => {
                for (let key in keyValues) {
                    object[key] = keyValues[key]
                }
            });
            resolve(array);
        })
    };

//call function to inject json key value in all array object
    injectKeyValueInArray(arrOfObj,injectObj).then((newArrOfObj)=>{
        console.log(newArrOfObj);
    });
```

Output like this:-

```
[ { name: 'eve',
    isActive: true,
    timestamp: 2017-12-16T16:03:53.083Z },
  { name: 'john',
    isActive: true,
    timestamp: 2017-12-16T16:03:53.083Z },
  { name: 'jane',
    isActive: true,
    timestamp: 2017-12-16T16:03:53.083Z } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];

for (const obj of arr) {
  obj.color = 'red';
}

// ️ [ { id: 1, color: 'red' }, { id: 2, color: 'red' } ]
console.log(arr);
```