# Javascript - Best/fastest way to add element to query result with fixed value

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have a node.js mysql query:

```
connection.query("SELECT id AS id, name AS label, status AS status from table;", function(err, rows) {
    ...
});
```

The result I'm getting back locks like this:

console.log(getBody)

```
[ { id: '1',
   label: 'Name 01',
   status: 'ACTIVE' },
 { id: '2',
   label: 'Name 02',
   status: 'INACTIVE' },
 { id: '3',
   label: 'Name 03',
   status: 'ACTIVE' },
 { id: '4',
   label: 'Name 04',
   status: 'ACTIVE' }];
```

To further cosume the result ... I need an additional paremeter 'type' with with a fixed value in the array. So result should look like this:

```
[ { id: '1',
   label: 'Name 01',
   status: 'ACTIVE',
   type: 'ABC' },
 { id: '2',
   label: 'Name 02',
   status: 'INACTIVE',
   type: 'ABC' },
 { id: '3',
   label: 'Name 03',
   status: 'ACTIVE',
   type: 'ABC' },
 { id: '4',
   label: 'Name 04',
   status: 'ACTIVE',
   type: 'ABC' }];
```

What's the fastest/best way to do this? Looping over the array? How should it look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add key value pair to all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827087/add-key-value-pair-to-all-objects-in-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
const newArray = array1.map(element => element = {...element, ...{type: 'ABC'}});
console.log(array1); // array1 won't be changed
console.log(newArray);
```

Or [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), this will modify your array:

```
array1.forEach(element => element.type = 'ABC');
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var arr = [
   {id: '1',label: 'Name 01',status: 'ACTIVE'},
   {id: '2',label: 'Name 02',status: 'INACTIVE'},
   {id: '3',label: 'Name 03',status: 'ACTIVE'},
   {id: '4',label: 'Name 04',status: 'ACTIVE'}];

    var new_arr = arr.map(function(el) {
      var o = Object.assign({}, el);
      o. type = 'ABC';
      return o;
    })

    console.log(arr);
    console.log(new_arr);
```