# Add key value (object) pair to all objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

My question is related to [Add key value pair to all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827087/add-key-value-pair-to-all-objects-in-array)

However, the solutions don't work when I try to assign an object instead of a string, int etc.

I tried to create the new key inside map function, but it only works with non-object variables.

This works

```
arrObjects.map(item => item.newKey = 'xxx')
```

This doesn't

```
var obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }
arrObjects.map(item => item.newKey = obj)
```

Output:

```js
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve'
}, {
  name: 'john'
}, {
  name: 'jane'
}];
var obj = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c'
}
arrOfObj.map(item => item.newKey = obj);

console.log(arrOfObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is `arrObjects`? Can you post the rest of your code please?

Comment: Also, you might clarify what you mean by doesn't work. What are you expecting? What is happening instead?

Comment: You shouldn't mutate the original array when using `map`. Use: `arrObjects.map(item => ({...item, newKey: {...obj}}));` instead

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a copy of object. By default object is assigned as reference.
here [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is used to create a shallow copy

```js
var arrOfObj = [{name: 'eve'}, {name: 'john'}, { name: 'jane'}];
var obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}

arrOfObj.forEach(item => (item.newKey = {...obj}));

console.log(arrOfObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can see some of use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-what-are-its-uses)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (spread operator)

```js
var arrOfObj = [{ name: 'eve' }, { name: 'john' }, { name: 'jane' }];
var obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };
arrOfObj.forEach(item => item.newKey = {...obj});

console.log(arrOfObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Alternatively, use `JSON`:

```js
var arrOfObj = [{ name: 'eve' }, { name: 'john' }, { name: 'jane' }];
var obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };
arrOfObj.forEach(item => item.newKey = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));

console.log(arrOfObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Remenber that objects are copied by the value of the reference, that was your problem, instead of a new object for every `newKey`, you had multiple references to the same object.

```js
var arrOfObj = [
  {name: 'eve'},
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'jane'}
];

var obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };

arrOfObj.map(item => item.newKey = Object.assign({}, obj));
console.log(arrOfObj);

// After some modification.
arrOfObj[0].newKey.a = "XXX"
console.log(arrOfObj);
```

Comment: Note that `Object.create()` doesn't do exactly what you say it does. `Object.create()` creates a new object and sets the *prototype* to be the argument you pass to it. This is not the same as creating a copy of the object. For that matter, making a change to `obj` will still result in a perceived change in the created objects, even though they don't share a reference.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha you were right, thank you, I changed to `Object.assign()` instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone the item, you are adding the same object to multiple property.

See below how it should be.

```js
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve'
}, {
  name: 'john'
}, {
  name: 'jane'
}];
var obj = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: "c"
}
arrOfObj.map(item => 
// clone the item 
item.newKey = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
);

console.log(arrOfObj);
```