# setInterval & the global scope: Running setInterval once on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user lands on my homepage, I use setInterval to cycle through some classes for a visual effect:

```
    var toggleSlide = setInterval( function() {
      $('#cs-main nav li.cycle').removeClass("cycle" || " ").next().last().addClass("cycle");
},600);
```

I'd like this effect only to run once when the user clicks on the splash page, and the site is loaded via ajax:

```
    $("#splash").live('click', function () {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#main').load('client.html', function () {
            }).fadeIn();

            var toggleSlide = setInterval( function() {
      $('#cs-main nav li.cycle').removeClass("cycle" || " ").next().last().addClass("cycle");
},600);

        });
        return false;
    });
```

The issue I am running into is (I'm assuming) because setInterval runs in the global scope, anytime `#cs-main nav li.cycle` appears on a page, setInterval does its thing. This is problematic because this class appears on my subpages, whereas my intention is only to have it run once when the user clicks on #splash.

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions **do *not* execute in the global scope**; they run in a new *execution context*.  [See here for more details.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722057/201952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearInterval()` to kill the timer once you are done with it...

Try the folowing,

```
$("#splash").live('click', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {

        var toggleSlide = setInterval( function() {
            $('#cs-main nav li.cycle').removeClass("cycle" || " ").next().last().addClass("cycle");
        },600);

        $('#main').load('client.html', function () {
        }).fadeIn('slow', function(){
            clearInterval(toggleSlide);
        });



    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like clearInterval is stopping toggleSlide before it can finish.

Comment: yeah, the above code will stop the "toggleSlide" as soon as the content fades in. You can move the "clearInterval" to anywhere in the scope where you know the effect has finished.